# Zend-framework-Accessing other form fields in zf2 filter

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-filter

I have a problem in Zend-Framework2 where I need to read/write the value of a different field in one field's filter.

I have a form which gets the address data from a user: *street, number, numberAddition, zipcode, city*.

I need to separate *number* and *numberAddition*, because I have some strict constraints when I further process this data. Number has to be numeric (int) and *numberAddition* can be a string.

Example user input:
number: 47a
*numberAddition*: [empty]

Should be filtered to:
number: 47
*numberAddition*: a

I'd like to implement this as a filter: if *numberAddition* is empty and number is not int then split number into number and *numberAddition*.

Is there a way to do this with filters or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

**That is not a proper solution**

In both the `FilterInterface` and the `ValidatorInterface` we can not see any `$context` variable passed in, so the solution below does not guarantee any forward compatibility (basically someone can remove the `$context` and your code won't work anymore, no need to wait a major version to do that as it already isn't part of the interfaces).

In your code, you can still use the `$context` as now you know what you are doing ;p

So basically :

```
class MyFilter implements \Zend\Filter\FilterInterface
{ 
    public function filter($value, array $context = null)
    {
        if ($array && isset($context['fieldName'])) {
            // do whatever
        }
        return $valueFiltered;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that `$context` is passed in by value and not by reference. I think I cannot edit the value then in filter A. I think I have to write two filters (for field number and field numberAddition) but then I have to make sure that the numberAddition filter is called before the number filter so that it can access the unfiltered number value.
I went with doing this work in the controller before the data is bound to the form. But I am still seeking a solution where the form is master of its data.

Comment: I'd say the proper solution might be using a custom hydrator to hydrate the object bound to the form, but I can't really help you there.